# Trying a web service multiple times - PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I'm building a function which interacts with a web service.

In the case where there is no response from the web service I want to retry 2 or 3 times incase it's a temporary glitch and before registering a failure.

Using PHP what would be the best technique for doing this?

Comment: `for ($i = 0, $success = FA:SE; $i < 3; $i++) { if (contact_service_successfully()) { $success = TRUE; break; } } if (!$success) { handle_error(); }`

Comment: The logic would be to create a function that performs the connection to the web service. If it fails, simply call the function within itself and have a counter variable to stop checking after x amount of tries

Comment: Regarding DaveRandom's comment, you could use the break command to end the loop if it is successful

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $response = getResponseFromWebService();
    if ($i++ >= 3) {
        throw new Exception('Web service unavailable');
    }
} while (!$response);
```

Probably though, if it doesn't work the first time, it probably won't work the second or third times either. Unless you're working with a really really temperamental web service, in which case you should probably look for a different one.

Comment: The `if` needs to be `if (++$i >= 3) {}`

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be. Depends on how many iterations you want...

Comment: True, but it makes the behaviour a little more intuitive... Your version will loop 4 times, normally if I write `3` I want `3` iterations. But I take your point.